# Tuleap - How to set html content in text field via SOAP API?

Tags: html, soap, tracker, tuleap

We are creating new tracker artifacts using the Tracker SOAP API.

When editing an artefact in Tuleap there is a drop down box to select whether the content of a text field is plain text or html. We want to fill html formatted text into a text field and have it shown as html in Tuleap. But we have found no way how to set the content to html, the html is always shown as plain text until the type is switched manually in Tuleap.

How can "html mode" be activated for html content via the SOAP API?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with SOAP https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/soap/view-wsdl#op.idp4277600

As you can see, the property "field_value" only supports three sub-properties: value, file_info and bind_value.

Moreover, the SOAP API is now deprecated so will no-longer evolve. The REST API on the other hand does allow to update an artifact text field with html. https://tuleap.net/api/explorer/index.html#!/artifacts/updateId_put